# Android How to make transparent rectangle with opaque outside XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created a layout so that the border is set with a `drawable` with round corners. When I set the background for a text view inside this layout, the corner becomes sharp.

Here is my XML looks like.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/det_event_time"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/det_action_buttons"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/detail_approval_round"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Approve"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/det_action_approve"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/violet"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reject"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/det_action_reject"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/violet"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/det_action_cancel"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/violet"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pending"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/violet"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/det_action_pending"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output I am getting is like below

[image]

Can anyone help me to make the bottom right corner as round when I set the background for the TextViews? Can we do this without using drawable for each TextView?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background.xml file with radius at bottom right corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#444444" />
    </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

And set the Textview background.

```
 <TextView
        ...
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        />
```

Comment: Good. But for every text view, I will need seperate drawable, right? Any idea to avoid this?